# Xcode iphone event listener

Tags: iphone, xcode, message

I need guidance for the following concept:

My `iOS app` has a text/messaging feature... I want to create a class that checks a database every 2 mins for new data no matter where the user is at in the application. I am assuming I would create a new class and just include it on all of my other files.

Is that the best workflow for what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];
Use this above method in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions for triggering the below method : void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler  Both method should be in AppDelegate Class. Fetch the data and save in your database

Answer (score 1):

You can probably run a repeat NSTimer with defined frequency from your AppDelegate and in the implemented selector you can write your piece of code to check DB for new data and may be fire a notification if it finds new data. Then you can have any of your viewController listen to that notification to get their UI updated.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(checkDBForUpdates) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Comment: This is great information exactly what I was looking for to get started. +1